# Alternative to process pipeline

Tags: pipe, subshell

Shell script on which I am working is having one SQL query which
fetches multiple column and multiple rows from DB:

```
get_names() {
    $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s usr/pwd <<EOF
        SELECT id,name,age FROM table;
        Exit;
EOF
}
```

Then, to read this result we are piping the function's output:

`get_names | while read sid p_name p_age ; do ... done`.

Now, because of `|`, a subshell is getting created, which I need to avoid.
Is there any alternative present for this issue?

We want to break that pipe statement to avoid child process of it.

Comment: A process must exist on each side of a pipe.  On one side it is `sqlplus` on another it must something else.  You could write a program to do the work of that while but that would still be a process.

Comment: Why must you avoid a child process? (this may help to get you the best answer).

Answer (score 3):

You can use process substitution if you're on a shell that supports it
(e.g., bash, ksh, or zsh):

```
while read sid p_name p_age ; do ...; done <  <(get_names)
```

This is required in bash if you want the final link of your pipeline to be your running shell (so that it may have an effect on your running shell):

```
for sh in bash ksh zsh; do 
     echo $sh:; $sh -c 'while read var; do i=$var
     done < <(printf "%s\n" 1 2); echo $i '
done
```

Output:

```
bash:
2
ksh:
2
zsh:
2
```

Whereas with a regular pipeline:

```
for sh in bash ksh zsh; do 
     echo $sh:; $sh -c 'printf "%s\n" 1 2 | 
         while read var; do i=$var; done ; echo $i '; 
done
```

the assignment doesn't stick because bash runs the while loop in a subshell rather than the current shell:

```
bash:

ksh:
2
zsh:
2
```

Comment: Note that among the shells that support `<(...)`, this trick is only needed for `bash`. In the others in `... | while...`, the `while` loop is not run in a subshell.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Interesting. I didn't know that. I've expanded my answer with a proof of that, if you don't mind. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score -1):

You could do it all in a single python process (other languages are available).